# How to change the coordinates of this metric?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I am trying to do a coordinate change to the metric

[image]

using the coordinates

[image]

What I got is

[image]

However, in [arXiv:gr-qc/0001037](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0001037) the author got the metric

[image]

Does anyone know where the factor of $2$ in the coefficient of $du \,dl$ comes from?

What I did to get the coefficient of the second term is to use

$$
-\frac{1}{f(r)}dr^{2}=-\frac{1}{f(r)}\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\frac{\partial r}{\partial l}du\,dl=-\frac{1}{l^{2}}du\,dl
$$

Am I using the wrong equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $r$ coordinate is a function of both $u$ and $l$, resulting in the following expression for $dr$,
$$dr = \frac{\partial r}{\partial u}du + \frac{\partial r}{\partial l}dl$$

Note that $\frac{\partial r}{\partial u} = 0$ (points with the same value of $l$ have the same value of $r$). We then have:
$$dr = \frac{\partial r}{\partial l}dl$$
Plugging in $\frac{\partial r}{\partial l} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}l^2}$,
$$dr = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} l^2}dl$$

We can now look at transforming the metric, ignoring the angular part:
$$ds^2 = f(r)dt^2 - \frac{1}{f(r)}dr^2$$
$$ds^2 = 2f(r)\left(\frac{dt - \frac{1}{f(r)}dr}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(\frac{dt-\frac{1}{f(r)}dr + 2\frac{1}{f(r)}dr}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Recognizing that $$du = \frac{dt - \frac{1}{f(r)}dr}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\implies ds^2 = 2f\ du\left(du + \sqrt{2}\frac{1}{f}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}l^2}dl\right)\right)$$

This gives the result from the link
$$ds^2 = 2f\ du^2 - \frac{2}{l^2}du\ dl$$

Also note that $f$ is now purely a function of $l$.